# Ошибка img2pdf pyhon

Tags: python, pdf, type-error, jpeg

Есть файлы типа `1.ipg`, `2.ipg`, `rtrrt.jpg`, `ghthh.jpg`. Их нужно объединить в pdf файл.

Соединение файлов должно быть обязательно 1.ipg, 2.ipg, остальные не важно. Код ниже работает, но на некоторых выдает ошибку

```
import img2pdf
import glob
import os

dir = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
print(dir)
dir_new = dir.split('\\')[-1]
print(dir_new)

with open(dir_new +".pdf", "wb") as f:
     f.write(img2pdf.convert(glob.glob("*.jpg")),  rotation=img2pdf.Rotation.ifvalid)
```

Текст ошибки:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/pyserver/1.py", line 13, in <module>
    f.write(img2pdf.convert(glob.glob("*.jpg")),  rotation=img2pdf.Rotation.ifvalid)
TypeError: write() takes no keyword arguments
```

Comment: Что означает "Соединение файлов должно быть обязательно 1.ipg, 2.ipg, остальные не важно" - файлы вида rtrrt.jpg, ghthh.jpg не должны быть включены в pdf или не обязательно должны быть включены?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В коде происходит ошибка, потому что метод write() не принимает именованные аргументы, такие как rotation.

Чтобы устранить ошибку, можно преобразовать в PDF до вызова write(), вот так:

```
with open(dir_new +".pdf", "wb") as f:
pdf_bytes = img2pdf.convert(glob.glob("*.jpg"), rotation=img2pdf.Rotation.ifvalid)
f.write(pdf_bytes)
```

Comment: По сути, причина ошибки в том, что автор случайно параметр `rotation` записал в `write`, а не в `img2pdf.convert` :)

Answer (score 0):

Причина ошибки в том, что закрывающая скобка стоит не там:

```
# Должно быть
f.write(img2pdf.convert(glob.glob("*.jpg"), rotation=img2pdf.Rotation.ifvalid))
# Было
f.write(img2pdf.convert(glob.glob("*.jpg")),  rotation=img2pdf.Rotation.ifvalid)
```

Получается, что вы передаете параметр `rotation` (поворот) в метод `write`, а не в метод `convert`. Метод записи в файл ни о каком повороте не знает, он умеет только записывать байты в файл.

Чтобы не путаться со скобками, лучше разделить операцию на отдельные строки:

```
pdf_bytes = img2pdf.convert(glob.glob("*.jpg"), rotation=img2pdf.Rotation.ifvalid)
f.write(pdf_bytes)
```

или даже так:

```
files = glob.glob("*.jpg")
pdf_bytes = img2pdf.convert(files, rotation=img2pdf.Rotation.ifvalid)
f.write(pdf_bytes)
```